# Template parameter: enum, class or enum class

Tags: class, templates, c++11, enums, c++14

Consider the following class:

```
template <class Endianness>
class bitcode
{};
```

With `Endianness` that could be: `default_endianness`, `little_endian` or `big_endian`.

The question is the following: according to C++14 and the following C++17, what is/will the best and common practices? (by common I mean those used (or which will be used) by the standard library or `boost`. (+ and why?)

```
// The enum option
enum enum_endianness {default_endianness, little_endian, big_endian};

// The enum class option
enum class enum_class_endianness {default_endianness, little_endian, big_endian};

// The class option
class class_default_endianness{}; 
class class_little_endian{}; 
class class_big_endian{};
```

(Note: of course the declaration of `bitcode` will depend on the prefered option.)

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't mandate any best / common practice. Personally, I'd never use the `enum endianness` (because it unnecessarily pollutes the namespace). Also, there will probably by someone here in a minute pointing out that the STL is not equal the standard library.

Comment: Easiest option might be to evaluate (the just released) [Boost.Endian](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/endian/doc/index.html) library to see if meets your needs. If you must implement your own, that might give you some design cues.

Comment: The sample code does not compile.  Please post a question with what you have actually tried, and where it goes wrong.  If your goal is to merely poll for opinions, this is the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to choose what fits your end:

1. `enum`: It is mostly for backwards compatability.
2. `enum class`: Can only be used when you know all the tags in advance.
3. `class`: Anyone can introduce new tags and you can make the tags contain data.

Answer (score 2):

`enum class` is most appropriate. It is a type-safe, scoped enumeration. You can compare values using the `==` operator, and also apply template specialization and deduction using template parameters.

`enum` alone is an *unscoped enumeration*. These are mostly considered a backward compatibility feature with C++98 and C. Values will implicitly convert to `int`, but those integers will be meaningless.

`class` alone gets you *dispatch tags*. Although this will work, you won't have the `==` and `!=` operators, which might force you into excessive use of templates and overloads.

Another pattern to consider is the *type-traits* pattern: a class containing static data members and functions, so you don't have to add more template parameters.

```
enum class endianness {little_endian, big_endian};

class little_endian_traits {
    static const enum endianness endianness = endianness::little_endian;
};

class big_endian_traits {
    static const enum endianness endianness = endianness::big_endian;
};

typedef little_endian_traits default_endian_traits; // depending on platform

template< class traits >
class bitcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

The choice is somewhat subject, but if you want to use this as a template parameter (e.g. for your `bitcode` class template), I'd stick with class/struct tags. This tends to make template programming simpler than mixing things templated on types with things templated on particular constant values.